# how to iterate html element in angular4

Tags: angular

I want a form like this-

```
   a = [1,34,12,2,1]
<input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_1">
<input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_2">
<input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_3">
<input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_4">
<input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_5">
```

But the number of input elements is dynamic and it depends on the array length. The id value is also dynamic. How to make such element ?
any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
<div *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_{{i+1}}">
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhjrhx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: but how we get value of a checked  checkbox ? because it use the same click function

Comment: And where is that mentioned in your question? Please be specific when you ask questions.

Comment: sorry for that. i need to make a function .<input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_{{i+1}}" (click)="Check()">   ,when i check one checkbox, i need to retrieve the value

Answer (score 2):

Use ngFor directive and declare index:

```
<input *ngFor="let item of a; let i=index" type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="{{'index_' + i}}" (change)="onChange($event.target.checked, item, i)">
```

And click(check) handler will look like this and actually you don't need id attribute any more on those checkboxes:

```
public onChange(checked: boolean, item: number, index: number): void {
// do your stuff here 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For get the value you can do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index" (click)="getValue(a)">
   <input type="checkbox" name="alarm_check" id="index_{{i+1}}">
</div>
```